# What are $x$ and $x_i$ in a Kernel Density Estimation function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I know that the Kernel density estimation function is:
$$ f(x) = {1\over N \, h} \sum_i K{\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)}, $$
where $N$ is the number of data points, $h$ is the bandwidth, and $K$ is a kernel function that acts like a window. I am confused about $x$ and $x_i$. I know that $x$ are the values on the $x$-axis and $x_i$ are $x$-axis data points but I'm unsure exactly how this works.

Say you have 200 data points. How do you know what values of $x$ to subtract $x_i$ from? You can discretize $x$ into 200 points on some interval, but what if you wanted a finer spacing (and there is a different number of $x_i$ and $x$)? It's unclear to me how exactly $x_i$ and $x$ relate to each other and how this calculation would be physically performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is a test point... where you will make an estimation, and the individual $x_i$ are the training points (each at the center of a kernel).

The $x - x_i$ term is just the distance of the test point from each of the training points.

[image]